# Multiple PDF From Original PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I'm using iTextSharp to create an invoice in PDF.

Now I need to create multiple copies of that PDF, adding headers such as "DUPLICATE", "TRIPLICATE", and so on.

Is that possible?

```
                    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 25, 25, 10);
                    System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileUploadLoc + "/" + "File.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, file);
                    fileName = Convert.ToString("Invoice.pdf");
                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    pdfWriter.Open();

                    PdfPTable nested = new PdfPTable(1);
                    nested.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.BOX;
                    nested.WidthPercentage = 100;

                    PdfPCell Tableheader = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Company Name", titleHeaderFont));
                    Tableheader.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    Tableheader.Border = Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER | Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER | Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;
                    Tableheader.Left = 45f;
                    Tableheader.Right = 45f;
                    table.AddCell(Tableheader);


                    PdfPCell Tableheader7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Triplicate for Supplier", fontsize7normaol));
```

////Above line has to be changed in each new pdf

```
                    Tableheader7.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    Tableheader7.Border = Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER | 
                    Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER | Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER | 
                    Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;
                    Tableheader7.Right = 25f;
                    nested1.AddCell(Tableheader7);

                    pdfDoc.Add(table);
                    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
                    pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but your question isn't precise enough to explain how to do that.

Comment: For instance: I would create a PDF in which the header is a form field. I would then use that PDF as a template, filling out the form field, and then flattening the document. Are you using iText 7 for .NET? Great, then I could give you an example. Are you using an older version, then sorry: you'll have to ask someone else, because I want you to do the right thing and use the most recent version.

Comment: I created one sample invoice. I need to create multiple copy of that invoice. one is for Original invoice, Duplicate and triplicate

Comment: I have updated your question based on the extra information in your comment. The answer is: *yes, of course that's possible!* It's even easier than I thought. However, you aren't telling us what you've tried, nor have you answered the question which version of iText you're using. Hence: the question still can't be answered.

Comment: Im using itextsharp.dll of 5.5 version.

Comment: OK, in that case, I won't create an example. You'll have to write one yourself, using `PdfReader` and `PdfStamper`. Or, you may decide to upgrade to iText 7, knowing that the 5.5 version has gone in maintenance mode. Maintenance mode means that no new functionality will be added to that version, and that support will be discontinued over time. If you are a paying customer, you can post a question to the closed ticketing system, but if you don't have a commercial license for your use of iText, you're out of luck.

Comment: Note that you are not allowed to use iText for free in a closed source application that is distributed as a binary or in a SaaS context. You can only use iText for free in such a context if you distribute the source code of your full project as AGPL software using the same distribution channel. (But you probably already knew this.)

Comment: In the meantime, I have looked at the code sample you added, but it's not really relevant. You're doing it wrong. You should create a document without headers first, then use `PdfReader` to read that document, and `PdfStamper` to add the header.

Comment: I just given sample code from my project. Its perfectly working for me.

Comment: Sure, but you're adding `"Triplicate for Supplier"`. How are you going to replace that? My answer is: your question is wrong. You shouldn't try replacing headers. You should create the document without headers, then use that document as a template and stamp different headers on different copies.

Comment: You meant i need to create document inside loop then i need to replace header right? My question is correct. My code says that i have to create this  pdf multiple time but header how to replace. My code does not show my question.

Comment: Wow, trying to help someone who isn't listening is really frustrating. Let me try once more: **CREATE THE INVOICE WITHOUT A HEADER** (mind the **WITHOUT A HEADER**). If I were you, I wouldn't create a file on disk, but a file in memory. Then repeat the following *procedure*: **LOAD THE INVOICE INTO A PDFREADER OBJECT.** The `PdfReader` class will allow you to create copies. Then **USE THE PDFREADER INSTANCE TO CREATE A PDFSTAMPER AND ADD A HEADER.** Now repeat the *procedure* as many times as you need copies. I apologize for all the shouting, but I hope it's clear now.

Comment: OK thank u. I will try to do it.